# SQS throttle Lambda message processing

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Given that many (lambda) sources produce messages into a SQS queue (1 lambda 1 message, no batch sending). Is it possible, to configure SQS to trigger another lambda with "batch processing" / throttling?
Let me explain:

- when a new message sent into an **empty** queue, I want to delay the trigger for certain amount of time (e.g.: 5min), allowing others to trigger processing of the queue.
- when new message sent into a **non-empty** queue, this should be processed after the grace period of the first message, so this particular message won't wait for up to the total 5 min

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to consume messages in batch every 5 mins? Do you mind the message's order?

Comment: Hi, The order of messages doesn't mind. Regarding batch: as I learned, batch requires different API, at least for sending messages.
The only what I need, if any message sent to the queue, wait certain time, allow others to produce messages, and after that time, trigger the processing once

Comment: For what you describe, I think you can solve the problem using Event Bridge to schedule a Lambda to run every X time and consume Y messages from the queue. You can consume messages in batch without sending them in batch.